# Drawing an array from google sheets for custom function, and it gets jumbled before I can work with it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a custom function. It gave obviously wrong answers, so I did a log, and found that it was jumbling the array immediately. Can anybody help with why?

```js
function MergeGroups(CatData) {
   
  for (var i=0; i<CatData.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(i + "; " + CatData[i][0] + "; " + CatData[i][1] + "; " + CatData[i][4] + "; " + CatData[i][5]);
  }
  return 1;
  }
```

so here is the first rows of data from the sheet that I referenced:

- Bin  State   Rank    Liberal Split   Population 5
- 5    OK  2   31.87%  1.      3,956,971 5
- 5    UT  4   32.83%  1.      3,205,958 5
- 5    WV  6   35.47%  1.      1,787,147 5
- 5    ND  8   35.71%  1.      762,062 5

and the log shows the states still have the right populations, but they have the wrong bin, and they're in a weird order, and some of the splits aren't right.

- 0; 5; NH; 1; 1359711
- 1; 5; ME; 1; 1344212
- 2; 5; VT; 1; 623989
- 3; 5; MN; 1; 5639632
- 4; 5; MA; 1; 6949503
- 5; 5; UT; 1; 3205958
- 6; 5; HI; 1; 1415872
- 7; 5; ID; 1; 1792065
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Fa9g2PJrbJvxdPWgXZKDRBUZcoPgU69pFPA6rfiTl4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share the sheet (or a copy) with public access (not request access) to try to reproduce it?

Comment: okay, I put the link up.

Comment: you can see the data on the "Comparisons" page. A11 to F65

Comment: `console.info(CatData)` and then view>Stackdriver logging

Comment: Yep, that looks right. 
[ [ 5, 'WY', 1, 0.27831005369682227, 1, 578759 ],
  [ 5, 'OK', 2, 0.31872580551526375, 1, 3956971 ],
  [ 5, 'AR', 3, 0.32652130341673524, 1, 3017825 ],
  [ 5, 'UT', 4, 0.32832272314572963, 1, 3205958 ],
  [ 5, 'ID', 5, 0.3352236502329119, 1, 1792065 ],
  [ 5, 'WV', 6, 0.35474246800339265, 1, 1787147 ],
  [ 5, 'LA', 7, 0.3558339705707648, 1, 4648794 ],
  [ 5, 'ND', 8, 0.35709129817860225, 1, 762062 ],
  [ 5, 'NE', 9, 0.3590076495804977, 1, 1934408 ],
  [ 5, 'KY', 10, 0.3626538651491369, 1, 4467673 ],
  [ 5, 'KS', 11, 0.3627996018918227, 1, 2913314 ],

Comment: If solved, consider adding a answer with your observations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function unjumble() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();
  let v=rg.getValues();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(v)), "Data")
}
```

This is what it is supposed to look like:

```
[["Bin","State","Rank","Liberal","Split","Population",5],[5,"OK",2,0.3187,1,3956971,5],[5,"UT",4,0.3283,1,3205958,5],[5,"WV",6,0.3547,1,1787147,5],[5,"ND",8,0.3571,1,762062,5]]
```

This is what the dialog says:

[image]